# Search and Replace in string in D

Tags: d

I'm writing some code in D and am trying to determine a generic way to search for a string within a string and replace it with another string potentially of a different length.

For example, something that works like this:

```
string x = "123XX456XX789";
auto y = search_and_replace(x, "XX", "DIFFERENT");
assert (y == "123DIFFERENT456DIFFERENT789");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, the `replace` function in the standard library does exactly that:

```
import std.array; // or std.string works too but std.array has the generic one
auto y = replace(x, "XX, "DIFFERENT");
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  The documentation on that one was a little confusing so I skipped over it.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of the docs are hard to read if you don't already know what they do; they are fine refreshers or references but poor learning material. A lot of string related stuff is also made more generic in D than in a lot of other languages and thus found in `std.array` or even `std.algorithm` rather than the first guess of `std.string`.... (the generic stuff is nice though, you can also use these on byte arrays or int arrays or anything else really too!)